# Создание выпадающего дерева в Django

Tags: дерево, django

Доброго времени суток. Только недавно начал изучать Django. Есть необходимость организовать выбор из выпадающего дерева. Что-то вроде SELECT в HTML, только отображаться должно дерево.
Есть ли готовые решения данного вопроса?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не правильно Вас понял, для построения древовидного вида меню удобно использовать [django-mptt](http://www.google.ru/search?aq=f&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=django+mptt)

Comment: Я смотрел данный алгоритм, но на сколько я понял, там реализовано простое отображение дерева. Например:
Глава 1
    Заголовок 1
    Заголовок 2
        Строка 1
Глава 2
    Заголовок 1
И, насколько я знаю, там при достижении последнего потомка, его ссылка кликабельна, то есть идет переход на другой URL. Мне же хотелось бы организовать простой выбор из меню дерева.